# In Windows Vista and later, is it possible to obtain the partial result of desktop compositing?

Tags: .net, c, winapi, screen-capture, dwm

It doesn't have to be the latest version, it is totally fine if it is a few frames old.

What I'm trying to do is to display the screen itself inside a Window, but I don't want the window itself to show up in the miniature screen. I can think about a few possible hacks to accomplish this. The first one is hiding (in some way) the window, taking a screenshot and then making it visible again, but there is a chance that it will cause flicker:

[How can I capture screen under my own window excluding my own window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495569/how-can-i-capture-screen-under-my-own-window-excluding-my-own-window)

Another option is through the Magnification API, but probably it still feels like a little bit of a hack.

[Excluding certain windows from screen capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080559/excluding-certain-windows-from-screen-capture)

I'm speculating that in a compositing desktop environment it should be possible to access the compositing engine and request a version of the compositing that doesn't include one or more layers. Most likely the result of this "extra" composition would be made available to the requesting application asynchronously, maybe a few frame laters.

Is there a way to do this using the Win32 API?

**Some other relevant resources**

[C++ - How to screen-capture, except for some windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445617/c-how-to-screen-capture-except-for-some-windows?rq=1)

Comment: did you ever find a solution to the above problem?